# Prevent a specific child div from expanding the parent div

Tags: css

I'm currently developping a website and encountered a problem with CSS.

I have a parent `div` containing 2 or more children: one containing the name of a user that sits on top of the other children, and just below 1 or more side by side `div`s which display items owned by the user.

At the moment it works fine, but if the user's name (top `div`) is larger than the total width of the `div`s below, it will expand the parent `div`.

I'd like to only allow the bottom `div`s to expand the parent `div` and make the title `div` use the full parent `div`'s width without being able to make it larger.

I created a fiddle about it: http://jsfiddle.net/mLxjL/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="matches">
    <div class="match-container">
        <div class="user-match-container">
            <div class="match-owner user">You</div>
            <div class="match">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img class="image-container" src="img-path">
                    <div class="thumbnail-count">2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-name">The Zeppelin of Consequence (Trading Card)</div>
            </div>
        </div> <span class="arrow">→</span> 
        <div class="user-match-container">
            <div class="match-owner friend">PfaU- [W] King Arthurs Gold</div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div class="match">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img class="image-container" src="img-path">
                    <div class="thumbnail-count">2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-name">The Lost Hobo King</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.match-container:before, .match-container:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.match-container:after {
    clear:both;
}
.match-container {
    border:1px solid #666;
    background-image:url('img/stripes.png');
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}
.match {
    width:112px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
.match .image-container {
    width:112px;
    height:130px;
    display:block;
}
.match .item-name {
    line-height:12px;
    font-size:10px;
    margin-top:4px;
    text-align:center;
    height:24px;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
}
.match-container .arrow {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    top:70px;
    margin:5px;
}
.match-owner {
    line-height:14px;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-top:4px;
    text-align:center;
    height:14px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    border:1px solid #666;
    background-image:url('img/stripes.png');
    border-radius:5px;
}
.match-owner.user {
    background-color:green;
}
.match-owner.friend {
    background-color:red;
}
.thumbnail-count {
    position:relative;
    top:-24px;
    margin-bottom:-24px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    font-size:18px;
    background: rgb(160, 160, 160) transparent;
    background: rgba(160, 160, 160, 0.70);
    padding: 0 4px;
    float:left;
}
.user-match-container {
    float:left;
}
```

Is it possible to do this without using JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried a `max-width` declaration on your title element?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't want to declare a max-width as I want my title element to have the same width than the total width of the items below it.

Comment: take a look at using "max-width: fit-content;" at you child element

Comment: [Ethan H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11279075) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68597232) saying "Thank you @Marisol-Gutierez Your comment worked for me. I added `style="display:inline-block;"` to the parent `<div>`. I used `style="max-width:fit-content;"` on the child `<div>`, and the child didn't expand the parent div. The text line wrapped as I needed."

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use **Absolute positioning**

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/chadocat/mLxjL/15/)**

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
```

and on the container div :

```
padding-top: /*the height of the absolutly positioned child*/ ;
position:relative;
```

Comment: Very poor solution for content with a non-consistent height

Answer (score 8):

If you add the following styles you should achieve what you want:

```
.user-match-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 22px;
}

.match-owner {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/mLxjL/16/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also just set height to fit-content so that the child div height grows as the content grows

Comment: Could you expand on this answer?

Comment: If you need a Div to grow in height as it's content grows, you just need to set `height: fit-content`