# Prevent a specific child element from expanding its parent element

Tags: html, css

This is what I have right now:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width:  300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.mainrow, .subrows div {
  width:   100%;
  padding: 10px
}

.mainrow {
  background: #CCC;
}

.subrows div {
  background: #DDD;
}

.subrows {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mainrow">First row</div>
  <div class="subrows">
    <div>Sub row 1</div>
    <div>Sub row 2</div>
    <div>Sub row 3</div>
    <div>Sub row 4</div>
    <div>Sub row 5</div>
    <div>Sub row 6</div>
    <div>Sub row 7</div>
    <div>Sub row 8</div>
    <div>Sub row 9</div>
    <div>Sub row 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is to prevent `.ops` from expanding `.container`.

I attempted a fix described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993947/css-prevent-a-specific-child-div-from-expanding-the-parent-div/20994123):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width:       300px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  border:      1px solid #000;
}

.mainrow, .subrows div {
  width:   100%;
  padding: 10px
}

.mainrow {
  background: #CCC;
}

.subrows {
  position:   absolute;
  width:      100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  top:        0;
  left:       0;
  overflow:   auto;
}

.subrows div {
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mainrow">First row</div>
  <div class="subrows">
    <div>Sub row 1</div>
    <div>Sub row 2</div>
    <div>Sub row 3</div>
    <div>Sub row 4</div>
    <div>Sub row 5</div>
    <div>Sub row 6</div>
    <div>Sub row 7</div>
    <div>Sub row 8</div>
    <div>Sub row 9</div>
    <div>Sub row 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But obviously this is not working. `.subrows` appears above `.mainrow`, and the layout is distorted. What should be done?

Comment: At least describe what you want to get ?!

Comment: It is not quite clear what would you like to achieve.

Comment: Your first snippet seems to work. Your second doesn't. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: What I want to achieve is literally stated in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your container relative positioning and add top:100% to the subrows

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width:       300px;
  border:      1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
}

.mainrow, .subrows div {
  width:   100%;
  padding: 10px
}

.mainrow {
  background: #CCC;
}

.subrows {
  position:   absolute;
  width:      100%;
  max-height: 100px;
  top:        100%;
  margin-top: 1px;      /* for container border to show */
  left:       0;
  overflow:   auto;
}

.subrows div {
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mainrow">First row</div>
  <div class="subrows">
    <div>Sub row 1</div>
    <div>Sub row 2</div>
    <div>Sub row 3</div>
    <div>Sub row 4</div>
    <div>Sub row 5</div>
    <div>Sub row 6</div>
    <div>Sub row 7</div>
    <div>Sub row 8</div>
    <div>Sub row 9</div>
    <div>Sub row 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the border of the container, it has not expanded to fit the subrows in (why you want this I do not know as anything below the mainrow will now be covered by the subrows)

Comment: Thank, you this worked! And if you want to know why I would like to do this, it is for simulating a `<select>` element.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width:       300px;
  border:      1px solid #000;
}

.mainrow, .subrows div {
  width:   100%;
  padding: 10px
}

.mainrow {
  background: #CCC;
}

.subrows {
  position:   relative;
  width:      100%;
  height: 100px;
  top:        0;
  left:       0;
  overflow:   auto;
}

.subrows div {
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mainrow">First row</div>
  <div class="subrows">
    <div>Sub row 1</div>
    <div>Sub row 2</div>
    <div>Sub row 3</div>
    <div>Sub row 4</div>
    <div>Sub row 5</div>
    <div>Sub row 6</div>
    <div>Sub row 7</div>
    <div>Sub row 8</div>
    <div>Sub row 9</div>
    <div>Sub row 10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I want. Your `.subrows` is still expanding `.container`.